# A new process with multiprocessing can run in main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

One library that I need to use with python3 (iperf3) needs that the library 'run' function is *executed in the main thread*.

I'm performing some tests to verify if a new process with the *multiprocessing* library will let me use the main thread of the process but it seems that with the snippet above I cannot have a new 'main thread' for the process.

What would be the recommended way to run a forked process as the main thread of the new process? Is that possible? Will a system like Celery help with this? I'm planning to run this from a Flask app.

Thanks!

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import threading
import multiprocessing as mp


def mp_call():
    try:
        print("mp_call is mainthread? {}".format(isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)))
    except Exception as e:
        print('create iperf e:{}'.format(e))


def thread_call():
    try:
        print("thread_call is mainthread? {}".format(isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)))
        p = mp.Process(target=mp_call, args=[])
        p.daemon = False
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print('Process ended')
    except Exception as e:
        print('thread e:{}'.format(e))

t = threading.Thread(target=thread_call)
t.daemon = False
t.start()
t.join()
print('Thread ended')
```

Comment: Don't use multiprocessing in your flask app. It will lead to all kinds of troubles with the WSGI server. The servers have their own process and threading system.

Comment: @KlausD. what would you recommend to use? Celery?

Comment: @georgexsh, For now, I did some modifications to the iperf3 module, and I'm integrating celery into my project to run those jobs, will report when everything is running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, all threads are dead after fork, you will get a new "main" thread which is your current thread, your checking method is wrong. `threading._MainThread` is not a public api, use `threading.main_thread()` instead:

```
assert threading.current_thread() == threading.main_thread()
```

because [main thread got replaced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/threading.py#L1334) after subprocess fork, no longer a `_MainThread` subclass.